# Connection between amortized complexity and worst case time complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, amortized-analysis

I have a set of n consecutive operations which each one runs in O(1) amortized complexity.
Can I say that the whole set runs in O(n) worst case time complexity?
How do I prove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give a code sample so I consider *n consecutive operations* as an algorithmic for-loop. So the task is to estimate worst case complexity of

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
   f(x) // O(f(x)) = O(1)
}
```

In other words

```
Sum(1,n) 1 = O(1) + O(1) + ... O(1) //n-times
```

or

```
O(1) + O(1) + ... O(1) = O(n)O(1) = O(n)
```